# Is it possible to sustain local oscillations in a three dimensional medium?

Tags: waves, material-science, oscillators, elasticity

This is a highly abstract question.

Let's assume a medium which is three dimensional and is so huge that its practically infinite. Now let's say we are in the middle of it. Now is it possible to conceive of a locally sustained oscillation or some form of disturbance which is localized in this medium and does not dissipate over time or at least is stable for a huge amount of time.

We can choose the elasticity and other physical properties appropriately.

So is there a possible disturbance which can be setup in this medium which is localized and lasts pretty long or is perfectly stable? If yes, what does equation or family of equations look like?

Comment: Is the elasticity allowed to be inhomogeneous?

Comment: @kfgauss as the medium has to be identical everywhere and continuous it has to be homogeneous.

Comment: Generally, localized waves require a boundry.

Comment: @r.w.bird that's exactly my question, can it create a boundary by itself

Answer (score 2):

It is a good question and of course has direct bearing on soliton solutions that might represent elementary particles.
The answer by @user8736288 would seem to be true in a linear, homogeneous medium.  However in a nonlinear medium it may not necessarily be true.  Moreover, an atom is in a sense a fits the description of a local, sustained oscillation in a medium. An [Abrikosov vortex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abrikosov_vortex) in a superconductor also seems to fit the description.  And, if the topology of the medium is allowed to get complicated, sustained localized oscillations are possible.  See papers by [Hestenes](http://geocalc.clas.asu.edu/pdf/ZBW_I_QM.pdf), for example.

Comment: +1 a nonlinear medium seems to be the only possibility. I would argue that an atom doesn't quite fit the bill, because OP mandates that the medium is homogenous. An atom would be an inhomogenous bundle of particles/charge, so presumably that wouldn't count.

Comment: Not a bad argument.

Comment: The only person who caught my true intent of the question, extremely delighted by the answer.

Comment: @Srinivas N Rao perhaps if you are looking for answers involving quantum /superconductivity  effects at the atomic scale you might reflect it a bit more clearly in your question. The tags are also useful for that.

Comment: @user8736288 I deliberately avoided it

Answer (score 1):

Fun question! I would say no, and here is my attempt to prove it: assume you have at some instant $t$ some local vibrations in a bounded domain (of say, max dimension $L$) in an infinite medium. These local vibrations may always be decomposed, in the most general way, as a superposition of travelling waves. Since the vibration is null outside of the considered domain, these waves are actually wave trains of maximum length $L$. Now if the medium is homogenous, the transmission coefficient at the boudary of the domain is 1. Therefore, after a maximum time duration $L/c$, (with $c$, the celerity of waves in the considered medium), all train waves will have entirely left the bounded domain in one direction or another.

Comment: Is there a possibility of waves able to travel in not a straight line??

Comment: If the medium is homogenous, no. The train waves will leave in their original direction.

Answer (score 1):

In thinking about this question, I'm starting to confuse myself.  The fact that a beam of electrons can produce an interference pattern tells us that an electron is (or is associated with) a wave.  (Presumably a wave “packet” of finite size.)  Consider an electron moving through outer space. If you examine it from a coordinate system which is moving with the electron, what happens to the wave? (And, what direction is it going?)

Comment: This is an excellent question to ask in itself